# Why I don't enter to the gotStream function?

Tags: javascript

Please look my code and say me why I don't enter to the function gotDescription(desc)

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true, video:true}, success, error);

function success(stream) {
    var video1 = document.querySelector("#video1");
    video1.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    video1.play()
    //rtcpeer
    console.log("1")
    var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection()
    pc1.addStream(stream)
    pc1.createOffer(gotDescription)
    console.log("2")
    function gotDescription(desc) {
        console.log("3")
        pc1.setLocalDescription(desc)
        console.log("aaa" + desc.sdp)
    }
}
function error(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

The is no console.log("3").

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please reffer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer callbacks as first and seconds params are deprecated

Comment: And what may I do to make it working ?

Comment: `pc1.createOffer(gotDescription)` gotDescription is successCallback, right ? And it is deprecated according to MDN. Use promise instead

Comment: Yes, it is success callback. So, why I don't enter into this function ?

Comment: Because it is not expected anymore, or there are some errors. Did you try to add errorCallback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use success and error callback, use promise according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer)

There are sample in that article.